# Why am I getting a 401 for a public route when using express-oauth-server

Tags: oauth2-server

I based my sample on this: https://github.com/oauthjs/express-oauth-server/blob/master/examples/postgresql/index.js

However when I try to visit the `/public` route, I get a 401. The URL I'm accessing is `http://localhost:8080/public?client_id=1234&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:4000&response_type=code&scope=email`

Here's my `index.ts`:

```
var expressApp = require('express')
import express from 'express'
import OAuthServer from 'express-oauth-server'
import {AuthorizationCode, Client, User} from 'oauth2-server'


const app = expressApp()

app.oauth = new OAuthServer({
  model: {
    getClient: async (clientId: string, clientSecret: string) => {
      console.log('Reached getClient')
      
      if (clientId !== '1234')
        return null
      if (clientSecret && clientSecret !== 'abcd')
        return null

      return {
        id: clientId,
        redirectUris: ["http://localhost:4000", "http://localhost:5000"],
        grants: ["authorization_code", "refresh_token"],
        accessTokenLifetime: 3600 * 24, // 1 day
        refreshTokenLifetime: 3600 * 24 * 30, // 30 days
      }
    },
    saveAuthorizationCode: async (code: AuthorizationCode, client: Client, user: User) => {
      console.log('Reached saveAuthorizationCode')
      
      return {
        authorizationCode: code.authorizationCode,
        expiresAt: code.expiresAt,
        redirectUri: code.redirectUri,
        scope: code.scope,
        client: client,
        user: user,
      }
    },
    getAccessToken: async (accessTokenKey: string) => {
      console.log('Reached getAccessToken')
      
      if (accessTokenKey.startsWith('XYZ'))
        return null

      const expiry_date = new Date()
      expiry_date.setHours(expiry_date.getHours() + 1)

      return {
        accessToken: accessTokenKey,
        accessTokenExpiresAt: expiry_date,
        scope: ["email", "profile", "openid"],
        client: {
          id: '1234',
          redirectUris: ["http://localhost:4000", "http://localhost:5000"],
          grants: ["authorization_code", "refresh_token"],
          accessTokenLifetime: 3600 * 24, // 1 day
          efreshTokenLifetime: 3600 * 24 * 30, // 30 days
        },
        user: {
          id: 234567,
          email: 'foo@bar.com',
        },
      }
    },
  } as any, // Just to avoid TS errors to test sample.
  //continueMiddleware: true,
})

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(app.oauth.authorize())

const port = 8080
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Running server at port ' + port + '...')
})

// Endpoints
app.get('/public', function(_req: any, res: any) {
  console.log('Reached /public')
  res.send('Public area')
});
```

"Reached /public" never gets printed. If I remove `app.use(app.oauth.authorize())`, it works.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This was pretty much due to the way middleware ordering works in Express. The line app.use(app.oauth.authorize()) coming before the public route ensures that the request to this route goes via the authorize middleware first.